# Flutter Spash Screen

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

[android:src="@drawable/grouptop" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqhBn.png)
How Can I Customize Image size of a splash screen image . I know by set its pixel size by image editing .
but is there any way that I can customize the size (length , width) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your launcher background like this in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

use this style.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
                 Flutter draws its first frame -->
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
            <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

        </style>
    </resources>
```

defined in manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: isn't working. getting an error when build the app. is there anything to modifies in launch bg and style ??

Comment: what are getting exactly  ?

Comment: this is very standard procedure it should work..if you followed these steps